# Why after deleting the script tag dynamically and added again also dynamically the old script functions and variables still working?

Tags: javascript, web

i have a script that has a function that should remove the old scripts and added other scripts, the thing is that if I removed the script and for some reason, one of the new scripts that should be added is the same as the old one that removed the browser gives me an error the variable name already exists. in other word, the removed script still lives in the browser, and its functions and variables are still in the memory and excutable.
below are the two functions one for removing the old scripts and the other for adding new scripts.

```
function remove_js() {

    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script[data-ams-reload='true']")
    let urls = []
    for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        scripts[i].remove()
        let src = scripts[i].getAttribute('src')
        urls.push(src)
    }
    return urls
}

function reload_js(scripts) {
    var body = document.querySelector('body')
    for (let i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var newscript = document.createElement('script');
        newscript.src = scripts[i];
        newscript.setAttribute('data-ams-reload', 'true')
        body.appendChild(newscript);
    }

}
```

does anyone know how to override this scenario?

Comment: You must reload the whole page. Because deleting the script from the DOM does not "unevaluate" the script within that tag.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, that exactly is the idea, i want to remove the scripts and its content without reloading the page @derpirscher

Comment: That's not possible. You can remove the script from the DOM, but that doesn't remove anything from the memory. What was loaded into the memory once stays there until the page is reloaded or it's overwritten ...

Answer (score 0):

When you load JavaScript into your page, it's not like CSS that's executed in "runtime". If you load JS, its loaded into the memory and then it will be always available.

A solution for your case can be achieved could be overriding the functions that you don't want to be executed from the JS you want to remove.

Something like this - original function:

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hello!"); //calling sayHello will print "Hello!"
}
```

Now, overriding it like this:

```
function sayHello() {
    return false;
}
```

That way, calling `sayHello` will return false and do nothing.

Comment: thanks you for your answer, but i want to do it without touching the other scripts, thats because im trying to build a library and everything should be resolved on my side so i want to override this in the script that removing and adding the scripts

Comment: Unloading a JS script isn't possible, the only possible thing you can do is either overriding the original script in your side or changing the references of your own library to something else, just like jQuery does. In jQuery, you can use "$" as well as "jQuery" for compatibility issues.

Comment: Thanks, for helping me out, i'll give it a try and i hope it works.